# Mysql AVG basket size of customer

Tags: mysql

Below code returns AVG basket size per customer, would like to make another AVG of result received from bellow query.

Is it possible to achive with single query, or i simply have to run another query were i will calculate AVG(previousresult) ?

```
SELECT
    AVG(total_captured)
FROM
    tblbodo_sales
GROUP BY
    client_id;
```

Bellow is result of above query

```
28.35
5.35
5.07
5.66
5.9
```

By AVG(previusresult) i mean the following:

28.35+5.35+5.07+5.66+5.9/5

Comment: What's your exepct result? what do you mean `another query were i will calculate AVG(previousresult)` could you provide some sample data?

Comment: Updated my question with requested details, hope it is more clear.

Comment: Did you want to get results on two columns one is for `AVG(total_captured)` another is for `AVG(previusresult)`?

Comment: CTE or subquery with shown query, AVG() in outer query.

Comment: Note that the average of the averages will not be the same as the average of all the data (unless the groups just happen to be the same size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in same query it is possible. Can you try the below one?

```
SELECT AVG(previousresult) FROM (
    SELECT
        AVG(total_captured) as previousresult
    FROM
        tblbodo_sales
    GROUP BY
        client_id) 
AS final_avg;
```